# How can I know if the camera is focused?

Tags: iphone, camera

I want to do this:
When the camera is focused, the app will take picture automatically.
But I found there's no way to detect if the camera is focused.

How can I know if the camera is focused?

Comment: We will need some more information, like how do you take the photo and what have you tried.

Comment: @rckoenes: Thanks for your help. Use UIImagePickerController or AVCapture, all is OK. I just need a way to know whether the camera is focused, and then the app can take a picture without user tap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On [`AVCuptureDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you should check whether focus is supported.
Not all iOS device support focusing, thus you really need to check wether focusing is supported by calling [`isFocusModeSupported:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/isFocusModeSupported:)

Then start monitoring the [`adjustingFocus`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1390577-adjustingfocus?language=objc) property. This tells you wether the device is focusing.

Thus while the [`adjustingFocus`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1390577-adjustingfocus?language=objc) returns `YES` don't take the picture, if it changes into `NO` the device should be focused.

Comment: @rckoenes I wonder why adjustingFocus returns NO while the camera is moving.