# Blurry images during object detection from iOS app

Tags: ios, object, detection, coreml

I've written an app with an object detection model and process images when an object is detected. The problem I'm running into is when an object is detected with 99% confidence but the frame I'm processing is very blurry.

I've considered analyzing the frame and attempting to detect blurriness or detecting device movement and not analyzing frames when the device is moving a lot.

Do you have any other suggestions to only process un-blurry photos or solutions other than the ones I've proposed? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might have issues detecting "movement" when for instance driving in car. In that case looking at something inside your car is not considered as movement while looking at something outside is (if it's not far away anyway). There can be many other cases for this.

I would start by checking if camera is in [focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12192280/526828). It is not the same as checking if frame is blurry but it might be very close.

The other option I can think of is simply checking 2 or more sequential frames and see if they are relatively the same. To do something like that it is bast to define a grid for instance 16x16 on which you evaluate similar values. You would need to mipmap your photos which manually means resizing it by half till you get to 16x16 image (2000x1500 would become 1024x1024 -> 512x512 -> 256x256 ...). Then grab those 16x16 pixels and store them. Once you have enough frames (at least 2) you can start comparing these values. GPU is perfect for resizing but those 16x16 values are probably best evaluated on the CPU. What you need to do is basically find an average pixel difference in 2 sequential 16x16 buffers. Then use that to evaluate if detection should be enabled.

This procedure may still not be perfect but it should be relatively feasible from performance perspective. There may be some shortcuts as some tools maybe already do resizing so that you don't need to "halve" them manually. From theoretical perspective you are creating sectors and compute their average color. If all the sectors have almost same color between 2 or more frames there is a high chance the camera did not move in that time much and the image should not be blurry from movement. Still if camera is not in focus you can have multiple sequential frames that are exactly the same but in fact they are all blurry. Same happens if you detect phone movement.

Comment: I decided on using the confidence rating per video frame and not processing the frame until I've had 99% for the last four frames. It works ok. Thank you for the detailed answer.